# How can I add custom columns for banner instead of column right, left, top and bottom?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, customization, opencart

I am new in OpenCart and I want to add more columns in:

Extensions --> Modules --> Banner

For Example I want to add:

In Position field:

Column Top

Column Bottom

Content Left

Content Right

Column/Content Custom *** <---

And want to place this banner on the custom position on the desired page.
Please help...!

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by 'custom' position? Pretty much, you can position your module anywhere using the predefined Content Top, Content Bottom, Column Left, Column Right (you mistyped it above by the way) and utilizing Sort Order. Do you want more columns, like 2 on the left or 2 on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Adding positions in admin

First, you need to open the module's language file located in; `/admin/language/*/module/` and add your new position.

```
$_['text_content_middle']       = 'Content Middle';
```

Second, you need to open your module's admin template file located in; `/admin/view/template/module/` and add a new "if position is set" statement at around line 50.

```
<?php if ($module['position'] == 'content_middle') { ?>
<option value="content_middle" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_content_middle; ?></option>
<?php } else { ?>
<option value="content_middle"><?php echo $text_content_middle; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
```

and in the same file add the option to the javascript function at around line 140:

```
html += '      <option value="content_middle"><?php echo $text_content_middle; ?></option>';
```

Third, you need to open the module's controller file located in; `/admin/controller/module/` and add a new line anywhere around line 35.

```
$this->data['text_content_middle'] = $this->language->get('text_content_middle');
```

You should now be able to see the new position in your modules settings. Also make sure the module's layout is set to "**Home**."

### Adding positions to your templates

First, you must add the position to the array located in; `/catalog/controller/common/home.php` around line 20.

```
'common/content_middle',
```

Second, you'll need to create the corresponding PHP file in `/catalog/controller/common/` (for example: "**content_middle.php**"). Add the following code, pay attention to lines 2, 50, 79, 80, and 82) as will need to reflect your position's name:

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonHomeOne extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->model('design/layout');
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $this->load->model('catalog/information');

        if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
            $route = $this->request->get['route'];
        } else {
            $route = 'common/home';
        }

        $layout_id = 0;

        if (substr($route, 0, 16) == 'product/category' && isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $path = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);

            $layout_id = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategoryLayoutId(end($path));
        }

        if (substr($route, 0, 15) == 'product/product' && isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
            $layout_id = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductLayoutId($this->request->get['product_id']);
        }

        if (substr($route, 0, 23) == 'information/information' && isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
            $layout_id = $this->model_catalog_information->getInformationLayoutId($this->request->get['information_id']);
        }

        if (!$layout_id) {
            $layout_id = $this->model_design_layout->getLayout($route);
        }

        if (!$layout_id) {
            $layout_id = $this->config->get('config_layout_id');
        }

        $module_data = array();

        $this->load->model('setting/extension');

        $extensions = $this->model_setting_extension->getExtensions('module');

        foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
            $modules = $this->config->get($extension['code'] . '_module');

            if ($modules) {
                foreach ($modules as $module) {
                    if ($module['layout_id'] == $layout_id && $module['position'] == 'home_one' && $module['status']) {
                        $module_data[] = array(
                            'code'       => $extension['code'],
                            'setting'    => $module,
                            'sort_order' => $module['sort_order']
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $sort_order = array();

        foreach ($module_data as $key => $value) {
            $sort_order[$key] = $value['sort_order'];
        }

        array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $module_data);

        $this->data['modules'] = array();

        foreach ($module_data as $module) {
            $module = $this->getChild('module/' . $module['code'], $module['setting']);

            if ($module) {
                $this->data['modules'][] = $module;
            }
        }

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/home_one.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/home_one.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/common/home_one.tpl';
        }

        $this->render();
    }
}
?>
```

Third, create the corresponding TPL file in `/view/theme/your-theme/template/common/` (for example: "**content_middle.tpl**"). Add the following code:

```
<?php foreach ($modules as $module) { ?>
<?php echo $module; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Now you can call your insert your position anywhere in your theme's **home.tpl** file by calling

```
<?php echo $content_middle; ?>
```

I'm not encourage to edit the core files in OpenCart, give vQMod (1.5+) or OCMod (2+) a chance!

Hope this help!